# Сохранение куки до ухода с сайта поправьте что не так?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно для статистики собирать данные что делал человек за каждый визит на сайт. 
Т.е. зашел человек на сайт, ему присвоился id визита, который сохраняется только на время пока он ходит по сайту. И при путешествии по сайту, в базу отправляется id визита и некоторые данные типо названия посещаемых страниц и еще некоторые данные.

В скрипте ниже по моей логике, запускается таймер проверки наличия куки с id визита, если куки нет, то устанавливаем id визита и записываем его в куку, если кука есть, то берем ее из куки и перезаписываем куку.

**Что не так делаю?**

У меня код такой:

```
// Функция установки id визита и проверки нахождения человека на сайте
function check_vicit_id() {

    if (!getCookie(VISIT_ID_COOKIE)) {
        var date = new Date;
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(5*1000));
        visit_id = rand(1111111, 9999999)+"."+date.getTime(); // генерируем уникальный visit_id посетителя
        document.cookie = ""+ VISIT_ID_COOKIE + "="+ visit_id +";expires="+ date.toGMTString() + "; path='/'";
        console.log( 'ID VISIT: ' + visit_id);
    } else {
        var date = new Date;
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(5*1000));
        visit_id = getCookie(VISIT_ID_COOKIE);
        document.cookie = ""+ VISIT_ID_COOKIE + "="+ visit_id +";expires="+ date.toGMTString() + "; path='/'";
        console.log( 'ID VISIT: ' + visit_id);
    }

}
function check_vicit() {

    setInterval(function() {
        check_vicit_id ();
    }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: А что у вас конкретно не получается?

Comment: вы показали объявление двух функций. а вы вызываете check_vicit в итоге? или это весь ваш код?

Comment: оффтоп: visit, а не vicit.

Comment: насчет vicit поправлю! нет это не весь код, остальная часть кода не нужна в принципе, там идет запуск функции check_vicit();

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, а не получается сохранение куки пока человек не покинул сайт, т.е. путешествуешь по сайту сначала назначается нормально, а потом при очередном переходе соскакивает id и назначается другой. Мне вот как-то надо сделать чтобы id сохранялся до тех пор пока человек есть на сайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом код верный, я не нашел проблем кроме одной: вы выставляете кукам слишком маленький срок жизни, 5 секунд. Думаю, они вполне реально успевают устареть между переходами по страницам, особенно, если данный код расположен у вас в document.ready (или window.onload). Выставите хотя бы 60 секунд. Меньшее уже сомнительно. На мобильных устройствах время загрузки для страницы вполне может составлять несколько десятков секунд.